# How to test a simple block argument in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write an expectation for this snippet of code:

`Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)`

I know the shorthand generates a block and so far I have tried the satisfy matcher, and this is the current version I am working with. I know this syntax is incorrect, and I will keep updating what I try:

```
expect(Sidekiq::Queue).to receive_message_chain(:all, :each) { &:clear }.and_return(true)
```

Comment: @max I understand what it looks like, thank you, but I am curious how to test it instead of a debate as to why. Do you have more feedback?

Answer (score 7):

This is the approach I used to solve this but I am open to other ideas on `HOW` not `WHY` as testing blocks can be tough, and I think this would be a great example.

```
expect(Sidekiq::Queue).to receive_message_chain(:all, :each) do |&block|
  expect(block).to be(Proc.new(&:clear))
end
```

Credit where credit is due: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1182